# cannot uprgade from 19.04 to 19.10 thence to 20

Tags: upgrade

At this point in time (Nov. 2020) I am unable to get 19.04 to upgrade to 19.10, as a halfway point to 20. What to do? The various tools simple say 'can't upgrade to focal' but we are trying to get to 19.10 first, as I understand that is necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) and [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/)

Comment: Standard releases have 9 months of supported life, 19.04 was released in 2019-April thus it's release name of 19.04 (*year.month*). You should have known when to *release-upgrade* (within 9 months of 2019-April or its release) and had a further *grace* period of 6 months before 19.10 reached it's EOL (though without security upgrades so risks if you were online with the box), but you've missed that path. The suggested upgrade now is via re-install (which is fast & easy for desktops, a little more complicated for servers). Either way the release format (*year.month*) should have helped planning

Comment: Stick to using LTS or *long-term-support* releases if you don't like the 6-9 month compulsory upgrade cycle of non-LTS releases.

Comment: Also Ubuntu has two rather different products.  Ubuntu releases using the *yy.mm* format (*year.month*) use *deb* files and are designed for servers and desktops.  Ubuntu also has different products using the *yy* (*year*) format, such as Ubuntu Core 20 which uses *snaps* only, has a far longer supported life cycle, but being a different product, you cannot upgrade from a 19.04/19.10 to a Ubuntu Core 20 system as it's a different product.  Ubuntu releases using *yy* format are different products, 19.10 *release-upgraded* to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (not the different Ubuntu Core 20 product).

Comment: You waited too long to upgrade 19.04 since the following release has already gone EOL.  If you don't want to have to upgrade every 6 months, stick with a LTS release.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS will be supported until at least April 2023 for all flavors and April 2025 for vanilla/GNOME.